# Strange extra non-ascii character left when doing replace in VBA

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to extract some titles from a powerpoint presentation, and when I do, I'm cleaning the titles of any non-ascii character by using

```
title = CleanUpText(SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.Shapes.title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
```

Where

```
Function CleanUpText(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
 .Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+"
 .Global = True
  CleanUpText = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With

End Function
```

The character that is left behind is apparently 
`Character 11 (Chr(11):   [Shift+Enter]       (vbVerticalTab)`,
which I found by running `MsgBox Asc(Right(checkString, 1))`
Any suggestions on how I can get a properly ascii safe string from Powerpoint in VBA

Comment: i think `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+` matches that ascii symbol.

Comment: What's the character code for that?

Comment: Do an `asc()` on it and let's see the return.